# How to restore Windows as a boot option in Grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows, boot-repair, windows-10

My Grub initially had boot options for both Ubuntu and Windows 10 (displayed as "Windows 7 loader", since I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 after Ubuntu/Grub was installed).  Anyway, I was trying to fix a problem with Ubuntu that I thought had to do with Grub (it turned out to be totally unrelated).  In the process, I tried using Boot-Repair from a live CD and chose the "Recommended Repair" - [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15155719/).  However that actually removed the Windows option from Grub.

I was thinking of using Boot-Repair to "restore MBR" to get Windows back, but then I would have to reinstall Grub (I'd imagine using Recommended Repair).  But considering the first time it removed Windows from Grub, I'm not sure that would work.

How do you recommend I get Windows back as a boot option in Grub?

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Boot Repair](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) cause it makes stuff really simple.

There is also a [command-line based solution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). Also worth trying if above fails.